# Is it possible to Redirect to login page after status code 400 in aspnetboilerplate?

Tags: single-page-application, aspnetboilerplate

It is AuthenticationProperties config:

```
 AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            IsPersistent = false,
            AllowRefresh = true,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(int.Parse("2"))
        }, identity);
```

after 2 hour user get error

```
400 (Empty or invalid anti forgery header token.)
```

how can I automatically redirect user to login page after getting this error?
Aspnetboilerplate SPA+MVC+Angularjs version 5.10.1

Comment: any suggestion?

Comment: have you found the solution? as we need the requirement as well

Answer (score 0):

You can disable checking anti-forgery validation by using the following code in you         PreInitialize()

`Configuration.Modules.AbpWeb().AntiForgery.IsEnabled = false;`

Does this fix your issue or you need to check anti-forgery validation?

Comment: Because of security leakage we don't want to disable it.